# ReportViewer control displays blank reports after changing the DLL version

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, reportviewer

I have an asp.net webforms application, Framework 4.5.1, that was using the ReportViewer control, version 10.

I removed the version 10 control from the application, and using the visual studio 13 toolbox, added the version 11 control.  Visual Studio made its various well-documented inserts into the usercontrol and web.config, and it works fine running in local host.

When I first deployed the application it immediately blew up complaining that it could not find Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll, and after I included that in the deployment, made the same complaint about not being able to find Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll, version 11.

I decided to copy all of the v11 report viewer dlls to the bin folder of the web application (Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll, Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll, Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll, and Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization.dll).

After including those dlls the error message disappeared, but all reports display blank (no error message on-screen, no web application error, no error or warning messages in event viewer).

None of the v11 report viewer dlls are in the GAC on the deployment machuine, but the v10 report viewer dlls are in the GAC.  I'm guessing this might have something to do with the problem I am having.

In sum, I'm missing some vital bits, but the lack of an error message has me stumped.  Is there any way to debug what is missing?

Comment: Go you get the plug-in "frame?"  I mean, does the control load but there's no data to display (or something like "Displaying Page 0 of 0 or something?), or is it that the rectangle where the control should be is just all white with no hint of the report control?

Comment: White, no hint of report.  On my localhost, where it works, the report generates a span with the id of the reportviewer control in it (in this case, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Reports1_rptview_ReportViewer").  On the machine I deployed to this span is not generated.  The form posts and returns nothing.

Comment: Sorry, working on legacy code, I just noticed that deep in the daisy chain of user controls the error message was being swallowed.  The error is "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=11.0.0.0", I will try copying that into bin folder and leave an answer if that fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this particular problem was:
1.  Also copy v11 of Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll to the bin folder.
2.  Check if the person who worked here before you was fond of using try...catch blocks to swallow errors.

Once v11 of Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll was added to the bin folder the reports generated properly.